# Why does my JavaScript works on here but not in my localhost or JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to create a dynamic webpage where each button displays a specific `<div>` page while hiding the rest of the `<div>` pages.

I deploy it on here, in my localhost, and on jsfiddle but somehow it's not operating correctly on jsfiddle and my localhost BUT it works on here.

I'm not quite sure why is that so?

My HTML:

```
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onClick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
<button onClick="myFunction3()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
Div2
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display: none;">Div3</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#div2{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#div3{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var y = document.getElementById("div2");
    var z = document.getElementById("div3");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div2");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var z = document.getElementById("div3");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";     
        y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myFunction3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div3");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var z = document.getElementById("div2");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";     
        y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var y = document.getElementById("div2");
    var z = document.getElementById("div3");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div2");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var z = document.getElementById("div3");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";     
        y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myFunction3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("div3");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var z = document.getElementById("div2");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";     
        y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#div2{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#div3{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onClick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
<button onClick="myFunction3()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
Div2
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display: none;">Div3</div>
```

EDIT:

My JSfiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/yvw4gwwh/3/

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: you are using `onClick` instead of `onclick` this may be causing an issue

Comment: @Noface HTML is not case-sensitive.

Comment: On jsfiddle it's probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of null
    at myFunction(navigation.js:5)

Comment: That means `document.getElementById()` is not finding the element. Maybe you have a typo in the ID.

Comment: FYI: Your 3 CSS selectors should all be merged into one since they all are exact duplicates of each other (with the exception of the `background-color` setting). The selector would be `#myDIV, #div2, #div3`. Then, you would have 3 separate selectors (as you do now), but each would have only one line it it for the `background-color`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your jsfiddle?

Comment: @Barmar It shouldn't be a typo since the implementation actually runs on here if you click "Run Code Snippet".  It just doesn't work on JSfiddle nor my local host and I don't know why

Comment: You need to give us a link so we can see what's different.

Comment: I just added my JSFiddle link that does not work

Comment: The fiddle works when you change `OnLoad` to `No wrap`: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yvw4gwwh/4/ -- the reason is in the question I linked to above.

Comment: @Barmar How can I set that on my local host so that it works?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special on localhost. It's a peculiar jsfiddle default.

Comment: Didn't you notice that the error was different on jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle error is "myfunction is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Change your Javascript Load type to No wrap - in `<body>`;
Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvw4gwwh/14/

[image]