# JavaScript 'myFunction' is not a function, even though it is

Tags: javascript

I've something like

```
let myFunction;
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction = function(param) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

and inside my HTML, I have

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction(1)">...</a>
```

Now it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`.

```js
let myFunction;
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction = function(param) {
        console.log('running');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction(1)">...</a>
```

OK, so what I tried was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction(param) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

but again, `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`. I've no idea, really, I used the first piece of code for a long time now and all of a sudden, that doesn't work anymore (or not in my context, or what ever). What's the correct approach to this?

I created a JSFiddle to show that what I tried doesn't work indeed (expected output is 1 or 2 in an alert, error given):
https://jsfiddle.net/kgdcwe4z/5/

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, see the snippet - your first code appears to work. Can you edit it so that we can see the problem too, so there's a [MCVE] to debug?

Comment: You can declare your JavaScript outside document.ready and use it inside your anchor tag. Moreover, dom related activities must done inside document.ready.. thanks

Comment: Why do you want to mix javascript and jquery? You can do it with jquery itself

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see where you're coming from, but that's merely the reason I asked here. It worked seamless in previous projects and I don't have any idea what causes this to malfunction.

Comment: It seems that the code works on stacksnippets but not on JsFiddle, and there is a simple reason for that.

Comment: @SalmanA will you share the _simple_ reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my JavaScript working in JSFiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/why-isnt-my-javascript-working-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: @user10984218 I posted an answer already

Comment: @JJJ how is that a duplicate? I just posted a JSFiddle to demonstrate, actually it behaves the exact way it does in my environment.

Comment: The duplicate explains why it doesn't work in JSFiddle. If it does the same in your own environment, it has the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Better to do only with Jquery like this below:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="1" id="test">...</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").on('click', function() {
       const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
       //doSomething considering the id as the param here
    });
});
```

> **Another solution with only Javascript is:**

```
const myFunction = function(param) {
    // ...
}

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="myFunction(1)">...</a>
```

> **With your existing code, you can achieve like this with closure:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    func = function(param) {
  console.log('param => ', param)
  }
})(func);
```

Updated answer link: https://jsfiddle.net/cjnp40e6/

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer the question but includes a nicer approach as for the parameters. +1

Comment: @user10984218 - if the answer is useful, please accept to close this question

Comment: it certainly is, but not completely. I understand the concept of the first solution, however, it doesn't fire. This may be due to the fact that I have multiple links with the id (only `data-id` differs every time), so perhaps jQuery doesn't fire then. What would be an approach towards this?

Comment: It will trigger

Comment: check the updated answer @user10984218. It will solve your problem with your existing approach

Answer (score 1):

Just move the function into the global scope.

```
// outside of $(document).ready(function() { ...
function myFunction(param) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is also a solution, why people have downvoted?